# Window.open freezes page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, printing

I'm trying to print an image on my page using a popup window method in JS.

When I click the printing button (which is the centered image) the printing prompt comes up but the hover effect remamins frozen and click events are no longer functional.

Here's the page I'm working on:

http://ateenk.co.il/sunincpn/

This is the relevant code of the functions and the print button:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $( '#printbtn' ).hover(function() {
  $( '#couponhover' ).fadeIn( 200 );
},function() {
  $( '#couponhover' ).fadeOut( 200 );
}
);});


function printImg()
    {
            var printWindow = window.open('', 'Print','height=400,width=600');
            printWindow.document.write('<html><head><title>Print Window</title>');
            printWindow.document.write('</head><body ><img src=\'');
            printWindow.document.write('coupon.jpg');
            printWindow.document.write('\' /></body></html>');
            printWindow.document.close();
            printWindow.print();
    }


        //HTML SNIPPET
        <a id="printbtn" href="javascript:printImg();" ></a>
```

Comment: your `document.write` calls are probably responsible for that. use `document.createElement` instead and it might solve your problem, not to mention being the proper way to do this.

Comment: It is difficult to see the problem unless you post the relevant code.  It is unlikely that it is only window.open that causes the issue.

Comment: @IvyLynx how do I use createElement? should I just replace `document.write` with `document.createElement`?

Comment: @SamDenton you're right, added the code

Comment: @user3160630 more or less, yes, but you'll have to do each element separately and connect them by using `foo.appendChild(bar)` where `foo` and `bar` are elements you created and this way you place `bar` inside of `foo`, as a child element. See more here [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createElement).